# Access members of a form in php

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig, symfony-forms

I have the following code:

```
$form_logistique = new Form\Form();
    foreach($aRefArticle as $k => $v) {
        $form_logistique->add(
            new Form\Field\Text('ref_article_'.$k, $v, true),
            new Form\Field\Checkbox('availability_'.$k, true, false)
        );
    }
    $this->form_logistique = $form_logistique;

    if ($this->getRequest()->isPostMethod() && $this->form_logistique->bind($_POST) ) {
        foreach($aRefArticle as $k => $v) {
            $aPrices[]           = $this->form_logistique->ref_article_.$k->getValue();
        }
    }
```

The form is send and it show on the template. The problem is when I submit form I get the error in this line:

> $this->form_logistique->ref_article_.$k->getValue()

**the error:**

> Call to a member function getValue() on a non-object

I repeat the form it show good on the template.

Answer (score 0):

`$k` is the key to the array element, not the element.

you should be using `$v`, assuming thats the object you want.

edit:

if you need to reference the key, then use:

```
        $aPrices[] = $this->form_logistique->ref_article_.$aRefArticle[$k]->getValue();
```

Comment: yes but the key isnt an object, so you cant call a method off it. its just an index.

Comment: then the array element isnt an object either.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this to access the fields of the form:

```
$this->form_logistique->get("ref_article_$k")->getValue()
```